# Selecting few columns of a result set as XML

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a simple `SELECT` statement which selects few columns from a single table:

```
SELECT id, name, phone, address 
FROM tmp_user
```

Is it possible to change this query so that only `id` and `name` are in select and remaining details are in a xml node?

I expected output of this select should be

```
id  name        extra data
1   Shreedhar   <data><phone>...</phone><address>...</address></data>
2   John Doe    <data><phone>...</phone><address>...</address></data>
3   Jane Doe    <data><phone>...</phone><address>...</address></data>
```

The last column is of the returned table should be of XML type with required data. I know how the entire result set can be converted to XML using FOR XML. However I am looking only for part of the columns to be converted. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you provide DML and data for testing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! No problem - try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    id, name,
    (SELECT phone, address
     FROM dbo.tmp_user u2
     WHERE u2.id = u1.id
     FOR XML PATH('data')) AS 'ExtraData'
FROM    
   dbo.tmp_user u1
```

This gives me an output pretty exactly like the one you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Neat, works as required. Why didn't I think of this myself :(

Comment: I also need to add namespace to the xml. Something like
<data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mst="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/">
<phone>...</phone>
<address>...</address>
</data>

Does anyone have idea how to do it? Since the select statement is nested I cannot use WITH XMLNAMESPACES.