# Selecting columns as XML with namespace

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to select some columns from a table as XML with namespaces included in them along with other columns as is. For example, I have a following table layout:

```
ID  C1  X1C1  X1C2  X2C3
1   A   1     2     3
```

What the query should return is:

```
ID  C1  XmlData
1   A   <xmldata1>
2   A   <xmldata2>
```

Where `<xmldata1>` would be:

```
<Root xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mst="microsoft.com/wsdl/types/">
  <Child attrib="C1">
    <ChildValue xsi:type="xsd:integer">1</ChildNode>
  </Child>
  <Child attrib="C2">
    <ChildNode xsi:type="xsd:integer">2</ChildNode>
  </Child>
</Root>
```

and `<xmldata2>` would be:

```
<Rootxmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mst="microsoft.com/wsdl/types/">
  <Child attrib="C3">
    <ChildNode xsi:type="xsd:integer">3</ChildNode>
  </Child>
</Root>
```

I have a good reference how to build the xml from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357203/selecting-few-columns-of-a-result-set-as-xml) but I'm not able to put in the namespaces. If this is possible how to do it?

Edit:
I've used following query attempting to get the required result:
    select 1 ID, 'A' C1, 1 X1C1, 2 X1C2, 3 X2C3
    into #t

```
;with xmlnamespaces('w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xsd, 'w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi, 'microsoft.com/wsdl/types/' as mst)
select ID, C1, (select (SELECT 'C1' "@attrib", 'xsd:integer' "ChildValue/@xsi:type",t.X1C1 as 'ChildValue' FOR XML PATH('Child'), type),(SELECT 'C2' "@name", 'xsd:integer' "ChildValue/@xsi:type", t.X1C2 as 'ChildValue' FOR XML PATH('Child'), type) FOR XML PATH('Root'), type) as property_data 
FROM #t t

drop table #t
```

Here is the output of its xml part:

```
<Root xmlns:mst="microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Child xmlns:mst="microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attrib="C1">
    <ChildValue xsi:type="xsd:integer">1</ChildValue>
  </Child>
  <Child xmlns:mst="microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="C2">
    <ChildValue xsi:type="xsd:integer">2</ChildValue>
  </Child>
</Root>
```

I can't get rid of the namespaces in the `Child` node.

Comment: Have a look at: [How to remove xmlns from child elements with FOR XML](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23697/2103)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this solution: [TSQL for xml add schema attribute to root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726426/tsql-for-xml-add-schema-attribute-to-root-node)

Basically, I did not put the namespace in the beginning but after generating the required xml structure I casted the xml to `nvarchar(max)` and replaced the root node with the desired namespace.

I also needed to use namespace prefix in the attribute. For that I used a pseudo attribute name which I replaced with a proper xml namespace prefix.

Both operations were done using tsql `REPLACE` function. Hacky but couldn't find other proper ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to include WITH xmlnamespaces , example:

```
;with xmlnamespaces('w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xsd, 'w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi, 'microsoft.com/wsdl/types/' as mst)
select ID, C1,
(select 
(SELECT 'C1' "@name",t.C1 as 'value'FOR XML PATH('Property'), type),
(SELECT 'C2' "@name",t.C2 as 'value'FOR XML PATH('property'), type)
FOR XML PATH('data'), type) as property_data 
FROM TableName t
```

Comment: I have this query:
`select ID, C1,(select (SELECT 'C1' "@name",t.C1 as 'value'FOR XML PATH('Property'), type),(SELECT 'C2' "@name",t.C2 as 'value'FOR XML PATH('property'), type)FOR XML PATH('data')) as property_data FROM TableName t`

and `with` is not supported there. Got any alternatives?

Comment: I changed the sql using your example. Note that I added the ;with xmlnamespaces line and also added 'type' to the outer node. It seems to work fine. Please try it and let me know.

Comment: With this query Property node also gets namespaces. I need namespaces only at the root node.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like?
select XML_COL_NAME.value('(/rootNode//childNode/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(64)') from tableName

Comment: I was not sure if using namespace was a must for you. Hope this help.